# Silverlight 2 via Windows Media Services 9

Tags: silverlight, iis, video, windows-media-server

I have been using the Silverlight 2 Media Player that comes with Expression Blend and also the sl2videoplayer from CodePlex and the issue I have come across is that I am unable to forward or rewind the video when it is coming via WMS 9. If I host the same video on a IIS 6 website, it works fine.

WMS was originally hosted on the internal name of *stream* on port 8888, where as the Silverlight page is host on *intranet* on port 80. This did not work and I applied the fix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328728) so that WMS can be hosted on port 80 to see if this would resolve the issue, but it did not.

I have tried using the mms://, rtsp:// and http:// prefixes and neither make any difference (I know Silverlight will fallback to http if mms or rtsp is used).

When trying to host the file on IIS 6, it was using the same internal name of *stream*, but hosted on a different port and this worked.

I used the source of the sl2videoplayer to debug and found that when it is hosted via WMS, the property CanSeek of the MediaElement returns false, but for IIS it is true.

I have also tried Silverlight v3, but using the same video players and issue remains the same.

Has anyone else had this issue with WMS 9? At the moment we only have Windows 2003 servers and no current plans to use 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that iis6 / 7 is running on 80 ? Or another program blocks the control protocol of the wms ?

example:

- iis = port 80
- wms control protocol = using port 80

Together it won't work. You mean something like that?